# Python Flask File Upload fails with 404 error

Tags: python, http, flask, keras

While following the Flask documentation / tutorials on how to upload a file I used this code:

**main.py:**

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify, Flask, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
import random
import os
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np


@app.route('/')



@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file2():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/uploaded', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename)
      model= ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
      img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224,224))
      x = image.img_to_array(img)
      x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      x = preprocess_input(x)
      preds = model.predict(x)
      preds_decoded = decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0] 
      print(decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
      f.save(path)
      return render_template('uploaded.html', title='Success', predictions=preds_decoded, user_image=f.filename)


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home')

@app.route('/map')
def map():
    return render_template('map.html', title='Map')


@app.route('/map/refresh', methods=['POST'])
def map_refresh():
    points = [(random.uniform(48.8434100, 48.8634100),
               random.uniform(2.3388000, 2.3588000))
              for _ in range(random.randint(2, 9))]
    return jsonify({'points': points})


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', title='Contact')
```

Everything seems to be fine in the code. I have checked several times.

Well when running it on localhost on my Windows machine.

I get an 404 http-status-code (page not found).
[image: e 404 POST]

I tried: on **http://localhost:5000/** and **http://localhost:5500/**

Also I cleaned my browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
@app.route('/uploaded', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
To
@app.route('/upload.php', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

Or, change your front end form to post to uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Matt seems that it works.. now the error is different. The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: Would need to see the POST data to help with that.